# Angular view does not change when $scope model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the relevant part of the controller:

```
summaryAlertsApp.controller('FinalizedSummaryAlertsCtrl', ['$scope', 'summaryAlertsSvc', function ($scope, summaryAlertsSvc) {
        $scope.alerts = summaryAlertsSvc.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts();
        $scope.settleAlert = function (alert) {
            summaryAlertsSvc.settleAlert(alert);
            $scope.alerts = summaryAlertsSvc.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts();
        }
    }]);
```

I call the settleAlert from the view, $scope.alerts is definitely assigned a new array but the view is not displaying the change.

I've been stumped by this for a while now, I can't seem to figure out why the view (which is basically just an ng-repeat over alerts) is not changing. I know the alerts array is getting shortened but the change is not reflected in the repeater.

Here is the view:

```
<div ng-app="summaryAlertsApp" ng-controller="FinalizedSummaryAlertsCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
           stuff
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the entire service:

```
summaryAlertsApp.factory('summaryAlertsSvc', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var factory = {};
    var alerts;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        url: "SummaryAlerts.aspx/GetAlerts",
        method: "POST",
        data: {},
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    })
    .success(
        function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data.d);
        }
    )

    alertsPromise = deferred.promise;
    alertsPromise.then(function (result) {
        alerts = result;
    }
    )

    factory.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts = function () {
        var finalizedSummaryAlerts = [];
        alertsPromise.then(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) {
                var alert = alerts[i];
                if (alert.affectedSummaries.length > 0) {
                    finalizedSummaryAlerts.push(alert);
                }
            }
        }
        )
        return finalizedSummaryAlerts;
    }

    factory.getNewSummaryAlerts = function () {
        var newSummaryAlerts = [];
        alertsPromise.then(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) {
                var alert = alerts[i];
                if (alert.affectedSummaries.length == 0) {
                    newSummaryAlerts.push(alert);
                }
            }
            return newSummaryAlerts;
        })
    }

    factory.settleAlert = function (alert) {
        $http({
            url: "SummaryAlerts.aspx/SettleAlert",
            method: "POST",
            data: {articlePMID: alert.PMID},
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        })
        .success(
            function (data) {
                alerts.splice(alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);
            }
        )
    }

    return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: Apparently there is timing issue here. You may have to reset alerts inside success callback of settleAlert, assuming this is an AJAX call. Can you create a demo link?

Comment: What does your view look like? What does your `summaryAlertsSvc.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts()` function return?

Comment: you need to share your view template as well as what getFinalizedSummaryAlerts function, otherwise I doubt people here can help you

Comment: I updated the post, apologize.

Comment: if you log `$scope.settleAlert()`, is it called more than once?

Comment: @DonJuwe Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: @DonJuwe I tried it. After I click the button, the $scope.settleAlerts is only called once.

Comment: What happens if you call `$scope.$apply()` in the end of the success handler? Does that have any impact?

Comment: No, I already tried that.

Comment: @pQuestions123: Ah, okay. Sorry

Comment: Is it at all possible to put something up on Plunkr or JSFiddle?

Comment: It's ok, I figured this out. I will post the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Since `finalizedSummaryAlerts` get updated asynchronously inside a promise, your scope only gets a state of that variable right after the promise is initialized which is essentially an empty array.

The way to solve this it to have `factory.getNewSummaryAlerts` return a promise and to update your scope variable inside the `then` clause of that promise

ie:

```
$scope.settleAlert = function (alert) {
  summaryAlertsSvc.settleAlert(alert);
  summaryAlertsSvc.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts().then(function(alerts){
    $scope.alerts = alerts;
  };
}
```

and

```
  factory.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts = function () {
        var finalizedSummaryAlerts = [];
        return alertsPromise.then(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) {
                var alert = alerts[i];
                if (alert.affectedSummaries.length > 0) {
                    finalizedSummaryAlerts.push(alert);
                }
            }
           return finalizedSummaryAlerts;
        }
        );
      }
```

Please read up on promises, there is a lot of weirdness that is happening in your service in particular handling the http response that needs to be cleaned up

**Here is my brief attempt to fix your service:**

```
summaryAlertsApp.factory('summaryAlertsSvc', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};
    var alerts;
    // NOT NEEDED
    //var deferred = $q.defer();

    // You assumed that a promise can be executed multiple times
    // which is not the case, it can only be resolved once
    // If you want to DRY up your code, create a function that returns a new promise
    function getAlertsPromise(){
        return $http({
            url: "SummaryAlerts.aspx/GetAlerts",
            method: "POST",
            data: {},
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        })
        .then(function(response){
            // most http responses carry the data inside the response.data value
            alerts = result.data;
            // we will pass data only to the chained then functions
            return result.data;
        });
        /// Promises resolve on their own, deferred.resolve is unneccessary
        /// Also whenever you intercept a promise in a then/success clause
        /// you need to return some value to pass it on to chained then/success functions
        /// 
        /// What you did here is intercept a value, do something with it and not return anything
        /// which meant that chained 'then' functions received an undefined value
        /// 
        //.success(
        // function (data) {
        //    deferred.resolve(data.d);
        //}
    }

    // THis returns a promise which resolves with a value of finalizedSummaryAlerts
    factory.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts = function () {
        var finalizedSummaryAlerts = [];
        return getAlertsPromise().then(function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var alert = data[i];
                if (alert.affectedSummaries.length > 0) {
                    finalizedSummaryAlerts.push(alert);
                }
            }
           return finalizedSummaryAlerts;
        }
        );
      };
    // THis returns a promise which resolves with a value of newSummaryAlerts
    factory.getNewSummaryAlerts = function () {
        var newSummaryAlerts = [];
        return getAlertsPromise().then(function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var alert = data[i];
                if (alert.affectedSummaries.length === 0) {
                    newSummaryAlerts.push(alert);
                }
            }
            return newSummaryAlerts;
        });
    };

    factory.settleAlert = function (alert) {
        return $http({
            url: "SummaryAlerts.aspx/SettleAlert",
            method: "POST",
            data: {articlePMID: alert.PMID},
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        })
        .success(
            function (data) {
                alerts.splice(alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);
            }
        );
    };

    return factory;
}]);
```

Please read up Angular $q as well as $http documentation for conventional use examples

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your solution. what is getFinalizedSummaryAlerts returning? a promise that resolves itself? When you write "getFinalizedSummaryAlerts().then", does that mean that the function inside then will execute when the promise resolves itself?

Comment: getFinalizedSummaryAlerts() does return a promise that intercepts the results of alertsPromise(using the ```then``` function) and creates a finalizedSummaryAlerts array which is returned when the getFinalizedSummaryAlerts() promise is resolved.

Comment: getFinalizedSummaryAlerts function is solid, the reason your code doesnt work is due to how you handle the http promise imho.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the method summaryAlertsSvc.settleAlert
Since it is changing the model on that the getFinalizedSummaryAlerts is pulling from to do its calculations. Since summaryAlertsSvc.settleAlert is changing the model on success, getFinalizedSummaryAlerts

The solution is to have settleAlert return a promise:

```
factory.settleAlert = function (alert) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: "FinalizedSummaryAlerts.aspx/SettleAlert",
            method: "POST",
            data: { articlePMID: alert.PMID },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        })
        .success(
            function (data) {
                alerts.splice(alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        )
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

then only call the getFinalizedSummaryAlerts once it is finished executing:

```
summaryAlertsSvc.settleAlert(alert).then(function () {
            $scope.alerts = summaryAlertsSvc.getFinalizedSummaryAlerts();
        })
```